# Animation CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-animation, cashapelayer

I draw a graph with this code:

```
CAShapeLayer *curentGraph = [CAShapeLayer new];
CGMutablePathRef linePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
curentGraph.lineWidth = 3.0f;
curentGraph.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
curentGraph.strokeColor = [colorGraph CGColor];
for (NSValue *value in arrOfPoints) {
    CGPoint pt = [value CGPointValue];
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(linePath, NULL, pt.x,pt.y);
};
curentGraph.path = linePath;CGPathRelease(linePath);
[self.layer addSublayer:curentGraph];
```

and it looks like this

[image: screenshot of graph]

But I have a problem. I need to animate the graph as it appears. Every point should move up from position `y = 0` to `y = pt.y`. Like they do in [the graph on this site](http://testofownership.com/proof).

How do I animate my graph like that?

Answer (score 7):

The `path` property on CAShapeLayer is animatable. This means that you can create one path where every y value is `0.0` and the animate from that path to the real graph. Just make sure that the paths have the same number of points. This should be easy, since you already have the loop.

```
CGMutablePathRef startPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
for (NSValue *value in arrOfPoints) {
    CGPoint pt = [value CGPointValue];
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(startPath, NULL, pt.x, 0.0);
}
```

Then you can animate the path by creation a `CABasicAnimation` for the `@"path"` key.

```
CABasicAnimation *pathAppear = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
pathAppear.duration = 2.0; // 2 seconds
pathAppear.fromValue = (__bridge id)startPath;
pathAppear.toValue   = (__bridge id)linePath;

[yourShapeLayer addAnimation:pathAppear forKey:@"make the path appear"];
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a `CAShapeLayer` subclass that'll allow you to animate its `path` implicitly (without having to declare a `CABasicAnimation`):

Interface:

```
@interface CAShapeLayerAnim : CAShapeLayer
@end
```

---

Implementation:

```
@implementation CAShapeLayerAnim

- (id<CAAction>)actionForKey:(NSString *)event {
    if ([event isEqualToString:@"path"]) {
        CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation
            animationWithKeyPath:event];
        animation.duration = [CATransaction animationDuration];
        animation.timingFunction = [CATransaction
            animationTimingFunction];
        return animation;
    }
   return [super actionForKey:event];
}

@end
```

Comment: There is no need to create a custom subclass of CAShapeLayer. CAShapeLayer already does implicit animation of it's path by default.

Comment: @DuncanC double check the "Discussion" of the path property in the docs: "Unlike most animatable properties, path (as with all CGPathRef animatable properties) does not support implicit animation."

Comment: That said, maybe there is a reason for that. I'm not sure that I would subclass just to add support for implicit path animation.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist, oops, my mistake. You're right (as usual) Sorry Cyrille.

Comment: That was my first reaction as well. I saw/remembered it when I went to the documentation to find a quote to use in my comment ;)

Comment: It's not always worth subclassing if you're going to do it on just one instance, but that one is straight out of my toolbox library.

Answer (score 2):

For animation you need use `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd` properties of CAShapeLayer.

See example `CAShapeLayer` animation in [Ole Begemann blog post](http://oleb.net/blog/2010/12/animating-drawing-of-cgpath-with-cashapelayer/).

From documentation `strokeStart`:

> The value of this property must be in the range 0.0 to 1.0. The default value of this property is 1.0.
>
> Combined with the strokeEnd property, this property defines the subregion of the path to stroke. The value in this property indicates the relative point along the path at which to begin stroking while the strokeEnd property defines the end point. A value of 0.0 represents the beginning of the path while a value of 1.0 represents the end of the path. Values in between are interpreted linearly along the path length.